# remove background image and add as image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to remove the `style="background-image: url(http://theoldcontinent.mgtestsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Schermafbeelding-2017-07-10-om-18.54.13-530x300.jpg);` 
from

```
<article class="post-featured post-6792 post type-post status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry category-tech format-standard mobile-video post-visible" style="background-image: url(http://theoldcontinent.mgtestsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Schermafbeelding-2017-07-10-om-18.54.13-530x300.jpg);" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnfNta6SosA">
```

and add it as

```
<img width="530" height="300" src="http://theoldcontinent.mgtestsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/kermiii-530x300.jpg" class="attachment-grid size-grid wp-post-image" alt="">
```

how do I remove the style with javascript and add it as an image, carrying over the scr url.

Comment: Remove class to remove style

Answer (score 0):

```
var article = document.querySelector('article'); // Use whatever you want to get a reference to the <article>

var url = article.style.backgroundImage;
url = src.substring(5, src.length - 2);
article.style.backgroundImage = '';

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = url;
img.height = 300;
img.width = 530;
img.className = 'attachment-grid size-grid wp-post-image';
```

That'll take whatever is inside the `url()` (i.e., the url of the image) and add it as the `src` to `img`. You can just add `img` to the DOM with `parentNode.appendChild(img)` (assuming `parentNode` is the element you want `img` to be in).

Note how the `.substring()` will chop off the first five and last two characters in the `'url( ... )'` string. That's because the browser will return the string as `'url(" ... ")'`, not `'url( ... )'` The quotes inside the parentheses also need to be cut out to get the url inside.